# Java sub-processes for executing KornShell (ksh) commands

Tags: java, shell, unix, process, subprocess

I'd like to use the java.lang.Runtime class in order to execute KornShell (ksh) commands.  What would be the best way for Java to print the standard output and standard error for any particular command?

So, if I declared

```
    Process command = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ls -l");
```

how would I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.lang.Process allow you to retrieve input stream (where output of your process is piped into). From there you can use [standard IO techniques to process it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). Following example will print all output piped by the shell command into System.out until EOF is encountered.

```
Process process = runtime.exec("ls -l");
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

for(String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
  System.out.println("Process output: " + line);
}
```

Please do have some basic understanding about java concurrency. If the command you're running is non-terminating, then the above loop will keep running

Comment: It seems like a command like "wc file.java" will skip this loop.  How would I get the standard output/error for a command like "wc file.java"?

Comment: The example above only reads stdout, to read sterr, use `getErrorStream()`. Please read java.lang.Process javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html